# Select DIV using its ID + addition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a div as selector is easy:

```
<div id="test1"></div>
$('#test1').doSomething();
```

I want to target only another div, containing the same `ID` + `_sub`:

```
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test1_sub"></div>
$('#test1').find( /* Same ID + "_sub" */ ).doSomething();
```

How can I do this? I know I can use `.attr('id')` to take **#test1**, but I do not how to extend this with **_sub**.

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/0gdrk7bx/)

*Of course it would be easy to target the `#test1_sub` directly, but image I have 1000 divs counting up `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, etc. and want to use this inside of a function.*

Comment: $("#test" + x), this must be working?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking because IDs must be unique on document context so `#test1_sub` would work just fine and anyway regarding your posted code, `#test1_sub` isn't descendant of `#test1` so i'm really not sure what you are expecting?!

Comment: I have tried to explain it. @AhmetCanGüven this does not work for me, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/0gdrk7bx/

Comment: To target all `sub` DIVs, you could use e.g: `$('[id^=test][id$=_sub]').fadeOut();`. To target a specific one, you could use: `$('#' + this.id + '_sub')` where `this` refers to specific `#testx` div. But your question missing some context to make it clearer regarding expected behaviour. And btw, sounds like a XY problem  where IDs should be needed but instead use relevant sibling selector or transversal method, e.g: `$('#test1 + div')` or whatever

Comment: ↑↑↑ where IDs **shouldn't** be needed

Comment: Well first true answer was from me :(

Comment: @AhmetCanGüven You should admit this question doesn't really make sense and even more seeing the accepted answer... ;)

Comment: I am sorry @AhmetCanGüven, but my aim is to target only the `_sub` div, which your answer does not include (even if your comment does, which was the fastest and correct one ;) )

Comment: @MarianRick No problem, I am happy you found a solution :)

Comment: That I am using a plugin, which appends elements into the DOM, so I cannot bind every selector on `$(document).ready(function(){});`. Inside a `.on('click', function(){})` I need to append another div `_sub`, and the only thing I got is a `var $current = $('#test1')`. Its quite hard to explain in a few words! But I totally do agree, I should target the div directly if I could.

Comment: @MarianRick please see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem and maybe ask new question regarding your former problem, not regarding the workaround you think would fix it

Comment: @A. Wolff thanks for your effort, but I have got a "ton" of code, which I am not really able to understand. Thats why its so hard for me to work with it. You can check another question of mine, where you can see my full code. Currently I am creating my own solution, because I need to send the page to my client tomorrow morning, and its quite hard, to let others digg into the whole process (as you can see on the wired way of asking my question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102463/royalslider-how-to-remove-a-slide-using-a-class-as-selector?noredirect=1#comment50464850_31102463

Comment: @MarianRick With a so short deadline, ya, go with it if that fixes your problem, you still will have more time to find a better way, later ;)

Answer (score 2):

You do it like this

```
$('#test1' + "_sub").fadeOut();
```

Note the quotation-marks containing "_sub".

EDIT: In your answer, you made up an example where you had 100 divs with ids like `test1`, `test2` and so on. Then you could select all elements with an id beginning with `test`. Like this:

```
$('*[id^="test"]').fadeOut();
```

Comment: but `$('*[id^="test"]')` will target all DIVs with ID starting with test, not only sub DIVs. And concatenate hardcoded strings `'#test1' + "_sub"` doesn't really make sense. How can this be accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

Set a variable and chain: (CORRECTED)

```
var target = $(whatever test div you targetted).attr('id');
$('#'+target + "_sub").doSomething();
```

You said you were going to use it in a function, so it would be targettable this way for example. Lets say when you click `#test1` a function will run on all subs based on the clicked test:

```
$('.testBoxes').click(function () {
   var target = $(this).attr('id');
   $('#'+target + "_sub").doSomething();
});
```

Comment: sub DIV isn't decendant of `#testx` DIV

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for the catch. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use start with selector to work with all ids.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gdrk7bx/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "*[id^='test1']" ).fadeOut();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">Test 1</div>
<div id="test1_sub"> Test 1 Sub</div>
<div id="test1_asdf">Test 1 ASDF</div>
<div id="test1_sub342"> Test 1 sub342</div>
<div id="test1_sdfsd">Test 1 sdfsd</div>
<div id="test1_45645"> Test 1 45645</div>
```